# highlight border in table on hovering

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, material-ui

I want the table row boundary to be highlighted during hovering.
Like this:

[image]

I tried adding CSS and the code for it is:

```
.ant-table-tbody>tr.ant-table-row:hover>td, .ant-table-tbody>tr>td.ant-table-cell-row-hover{
  background: #fafafa;
  color: #091E42 
} 

.theme-dark .ant-table-tbody>tr.ant-table-row:hover>td, .ant-table-tbody>tr>td.ant-table-cell-row-hover{
  background:#242424;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #CDD6E0 !important;
}
```

But in this the highlight is coming between the columns also:
[image]

Can anyone suggest how can I add CSS for this?

Comment: This is because you are adding the border also on the `td`-element. Try setting it on `tr` only.

Comment: @OuttaSpaceTime you should never overstyle TR elements. You should treat them purely as semantic wrappers. Besides that, it's TR does not accepts `border`.

Answer (score 1):

- Set two CSS vars `--color-border: #888;` and `--color-border-hover: #fff;`
- Smartly set your your borders on the tables cell elements. Focus on the `border-top` and set the `border-bottom` only on the last row's TD
- Only the `:first-child` and `:last-child` TH and TD should have the left / right borders set.
- Finally, on `tbody tr:hover` simply set the `--color-border:` value to `var(--color-border-hover);`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 1rem/1.4 sans-serif;
  background-color: #181818;
  color: #eee;
}

table {
  --color-border: #888;
  --color-border-hover: #fff;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  border-spacing: 0;
  th,
  td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    border-top: 1px solid var(--color-border);
  }
  thead {
    th {
      &:first-child {
        border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
        border-left: 1px solid var(--color-border);
      }
      &:last-child {
        border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
        border-right: 1px solid var(--color-border);
      }
    }
  }
  tbody {
    td {
      transition: background-color 0.26s, border-color 0.26s;
      &:first-child {
        border-left: 1px solid var(--color-border);
      }
      &:last-child {
        border-right: 1px solid var(--color-border);
      }
    }
    tr:last-child {
      td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid var(--color-border);
      }
    }
    tr:hover {
      --color-border: var(--color-border-hover);
      td {
        background-color: hsla(0 100% 100% / 0.1);
      }
      &+tr td {
        border-top-color: var(--color-border-hover);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Foo</td>
      <td>Bar</td>
      <td>fbar@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Baz</td>
      <td>Fiz</td>
      <td>bfiz@mail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Stack</td>
      <td>Overflow</td>
      <td>stove@domain.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```